# Fastest query to see if it returns at least one row

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I just need to know if a query returns or not a record.

Of course I can do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE conds;
```

But this returns the exact number of rows (of course), and I don't need this overhead.

So I thought this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE conds LIMIT 1) as t1
```

Limiting the internal query to 1.

Is this faster? Or considering I am doing a subquery it cancels the benefits of `LIMIT 1`?

Note: for everyone asking theirself, I can't apply `LIMIT 1` to the first query because it doens't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The inner-select in the second query is redundant.
If you just want to check at-least of one row :-

```
SELECT 1 FROM tbl  // return 1
WHERE conds        // depends on your index and query
ORDER BY NULL      // avoid file-sort
LIMIT 1;           // minimum row
```

Comment: And then I need to call a `mysql_num_rows($result)` ? (Let's say I am using mysql lib)

Comment: Is ORDER BY NULL necessarly? without providing it wouldn't be the same?

Comment: not necessary, and you are not interested on the sorted result

Answer (score 3):

Why not just:

```
SELECT 1 FROM tbl WHERE conds LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE CONDITION)
```

Or something like:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE id IN( 1000, 1001))
```

Comment: Would `EXISTS(...)` be more efficient than a `SELECT ... LIMIT 1`?